# How do you compare objects with different properties in run-time?

Tags: c#, algorithm, logic

[image]

My code structure is something like this

```
class Drawing()
{
ObjectType = "Drawing";
}

class Shape() : Drawing()
{
DrawingType = "Shape";
}

class square() : Shape()
{
ShapeType = "square";
}

class circle() : Shape()
{
ShapeType = "circle";
}

class triangle() : Shape()
{
ShapeType = "triangle";
}

class lines() : Drawing()
{
DrawingType = "lines";
}

class horizontal() : lines()
{
linesType = "horizontal";
}

class vertical() : lines()
{
linesType = "vertical";
}

etc...
```

I am trying to figure out the right logic in how to solve this problem so the picture is a simple representation of what I have.

I have a object structure of something like in the picture where they're all inheriting the level above them. They all have properties of its type. They would all have ObjectType, and the 2nd level has DrawingType, and the 3rd level has either ShapeType, LineType, or PointType...

So for example, square would have

```
square {
ObjectType = "drawing";
DrawingType = "shapes";
ShapeType = "square"
}
```

However, vertical would have different properties

```
vertical {
    ObjectType = "drawing";
    DrawingType = "lines";
    LineType = "vertical"
    }
```

Now my problem is, lets say I wanted a user to select something based on their input, how would i do it?
Like lets say the user typed "square", how would I select square? It would be easy if the properties were the same cause I could just compare them. But how would I do it with a structure like this?

Comment: I would add your actual class structure rather than strange pseudocode. The image might be helpful, but the code for the hierarchy should be included.

Comment: @Llama ok, i added it, but i didnt think it was going to be helpful at all.. if anything it might be a little more confusing

Comment: No, that's certainly clarified it for me. I was expecting `Drawing` was a containing type (like the root object of an SVG), and then I thought `Shapes`, `Lines`, and `Point` were all containers for many Shape-derived objects (I missed the line in the question text itself about inheritance). It's clearer now that you're talking about an inheritance relationship where "Drawing" is the base type and all the rest are derived types. Thank you. I would suggest looking at the `IEquatable` interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

As these all classes are derived from one base class hence all the child classes contains the property coming from parents. Object level comparison will lead you comparison of one Drawing object to another as all the objects are derived from there only. Hence i have implemented IComparer to get your desired result ->

Here is the code ->>

**Main Class** :

```
Drawing drawing1 = new Drawing();
        Drawing drawing2 = new Drawing();
        drawing2.ObjectType = "newdrawing";

        Shape shape = new Shape();
        triangle triangle1 = new triangle();
        triangle triangle2 = new triangle();
        triangle2.ShapeType = "another";

        //all -1 is not equals and 0 is equals
        int result1 = drawing1.Compare(drawing1, drawing2);
        int result2 = drawing1.Compare(drawing1, drawing1);

        int result3 = drawing1.Compare(drawing1, shape);
        int result4 = shape.Compare(shape, triangle1);

        int result5 = triangle1.Compare(triangle1, triangle2);
```

**Other classes** :

```
public class Drawing : IComparer
{
    public string ObjectType { get; set; } = "Drawing";

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        //returning 0 is equals
        if (x.GetType().Name == y.GetType().Name)
        {
            switch (x.GetType().Name)
            {
                case "Drawing":
                    return ((Drawing)x).ObjectType == ((Drawing)y).ObjectType ? 0 : -1;
                case "Shape":
                    return ((Shape)x).DrawingType == ((Shape)y).DrawingType ? 0 : -1;
                case "square":
                    return ((square)x).ShapeType == ((square)y).ShapeType ? 0 : -1;
                case "triangle":
                    return ((triangle)x).ShapeType == ((triangle)y).ShapeType ? 0 : -1;
                default:
                    return -1; // Not equal
            }
        }
        return -1; // Not equal
    }
}

class Shape : Drawing
{
    public string DrawingType { get; set; } = "Shape";

}

class square : Shape
{
    public string ShapeType { get; set; } = "square";
}

class circle : Shape
{
    public string ShapeType { get; set; } = "circle";
}

class triangle : Shape
{
    public string ShapeType { get; set; } = "triangle";
}

class lines : Drawing
{
    public string DrawingType { get; set; } = "lines";
}

class horizontal : lines
{
    public string linesType { get; set; } = "horizontal";
}

class vertical : lines
{
    public string linesType { get; set; } = "vertical";
}
```

Hope this will work for you. please write back with you code snippet specifically not working. Cheers

Comment: What if there isn't a sensible way to determine if an object is "less than" or "more than" another object?

Comment: Yes, there you can compare object as == for shallow copy but it will not work for deep copy

Comment: Agreed, IEquatable is more appropriate when you have same type of object to compare. Also you need to implement in all the classes to compare. Something like this  Code -> public class City : IEquatable<City>

Comment: It has two Objects to compare from Parent Class and you can provide your implementation. Please refer the code above. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can make a separate class as well for comparison. As here base class is there who can solve purpose of all, hence you can control implementation rather create helper kind of things.  'IComparable' is not right choice when you have heterogeneous objects to cover, hope this make sense.

Comment: No Mate, IComparer<T> will give you same implementation along with few properties. Try to implement IComparer<T> interface and you will land on the same place. Trust me.